# scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: and CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have a question that I got by reading Apple's documentation. When it comes to `CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey` Apple's documentation states:

> An array (an instance of NSArray) of service UUIDs (represented by
>   CBUUID objects) that you want to scan for.
>
> Specifying this scan option causes the central manager to also scan
>   for peripherals soliciting any of the services contained in the array.

On regard of `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:`'s first argument, however:

> An array of CBUUID objects that the app is interested in. In this
>   case, each CBUUID object represents the UUID of a service that a
>   peripheral is advertising.

So what's the difference? Why use one or the other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically the Bluetooth peripheral advertises services and the central scans for those services.  This is the case covered by the first parameter.

In some cases, however, the behaviour is reversed - the central offers the service and the peripheral looks for it.  This is called service solicitation.  When you supply an array of service identifiers using `CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey` you are providing the list of services that the central will 'advertise' to peripherals.

It is still the responsibility of the central to initiate the connection, so once a peripheral is identified that is soliciting for one of those services, you will receive a call to the `didDiscoverPeripheral` method as per usual.

Comment: "Solicited" services makes much more sense now ;) thanks !

Comment: Well explained.